# Определить местоположение по данным

Tags: html5, геолокация

По IP не получается. Показывает город, в котором находится мой провайдер, а не я.

По координатам получается точно определить только на мобильных устройствах, на компьютере вообще показывает какую-то пустыню, где нет населенных пунктов.

Google и другие крупные сервисы используют HTML5 Geolocation, но у них получается определить хотя бы действующий город. Какую магию они используют?

Comment: По IP и используют. Просто у них наверно более актуальная и корректная база этих самых городов

Comment: Провайдер отдает свой IP адрес, а не пользователя. К тому же у Google запросы на получение местоположения, значит это точно HTML5 Geolocation. Только как они точно определяют местоположение. Вот в чём вопрос. Ведь я тоже использую HTML5 Geolocation, а значит, что Google, что мне приходят одни и те координаты.

Comment: IP-адреса любых пользователей по определению принадлежат тому интернет-провайдеру, услугами которого эти пользователи пользуются. Город пользователя и город провайдера совпадают в подавляющем большинстве случаев — этим и пользуются все аналогичные сервисы, включая гугл.